# Android Ringtonemanager returns RESULT_CANCELED when "Silent" is selected

Tags: android, ringtonemanager

I am using the ringtone picker provided by the Android RingtoneManager.
When I choose ringtone and press OK, resultCode is Activity.RESULT_OK and data contains the ringtone's URI.
When I press Cancel resultCode is Activity.RESULT_CANCELED.
So far, so good, this works as expected.
But when I choose Silent or None and press OK, resultCode is also RESULT_CANCELED, so I can't tell, whether the user has just canceled the picker dialog or really does not want a ringtone to be played.

What is going wrong here?

```
const val PICK_TONE = 1

btnRtp.setOnClickListener {
            intent = Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER)
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Choose ringtone")
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_TONE)
        }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)     
        if (requestCode == PICK_TONE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                textView.text = "Canceled"
            } else
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                textView.text = ""
                var toneUri: Uri? =
                    data?.getParcelableExtra<Uri>(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI)
                textView.text = toneUri?.toString() ?: "Silent"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, true);

Comment: Silent/None is already shown by the ringtone picker, I think it is default behaviour. But the problem is, I do not get RESULT_OK but RESULT_CANCELED when Silent is chosen with the OK button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself. Turns out, that if you do not pass a URI via `intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, currentTone)` Silent is preselected by the picker but clicking OK does not give RESULT_OK. When I pass a valid URI to the picker the picker returns RESULT_OK when clicking OK no matter what tone was selected. Docs could be a little more precise here...